# NodeJS - parallel execution of http requests

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I need to simulate a user scenario of parallel and sequential executions of http request (invoke a web service and measure time to deliver the response)

```
                function 1
 function2  |   function3      | function4
```

So function1 execute first as soon as it's done I need to perform parallel execution of functions 2, 3 and 4
How do I control the execution of function 2,3 and 5 and force parallel execution? 
is this possible with nodejs? does async.parallel provide this result?
is there any valid multi-threading in NodeJS to allow real parallel execution?

Answer (score -2):

Create async functions:

```
var function2 = function(callback){
    process.nextTick(function(){
        callback();
    });
};
var function3 = function(callback){
    process.nextTick(function(){
        callback();
    });
};
var function4 = function(callback){
        process.nextTick(function(){
            callback();
        });
    };
```

Call:

```
function1(); //sync
function2(function(){}); //async
function3(function(){}); //async
function4(function(){}); //async
```

Comment: I didn't downvote (maybe I should?) but this doesn't help with his situation because the http requests are all async. The way to do it the way he wants to is to launch the 3 requests from the callback of the first request.

Comment: the question is if I launch the 3 requests from the callback will the execution be parallel ? and what's the proof of that ?

Comment: it will be async, meaning func3 can start/finish before func2 and func4 can start/finish before func3.

Comment: yes I know that but will the execution be simultaneous, regardless the time every function takes ?
and is async.parallel the way to do it

Comment: I would guess that you have no control over it, because the way javascript works. Regarding the async.parallel, all it does is: allow you to execute a callback, once all functions are complete.

Comment: so how can I have control over my functions to make the execution parallel ?